# Compare the files in two folders using a shell script

Tags: sh

I want to compare two folders to see if the file inside are the same or not. If it is the same then I moved those files into another folder. For example:

```
    f1                     f2
  ------                --------
  test1                 test3
  test2                 test4
                        test1
```

Here the `test1.txt` file is available on both folders, so I need to move that file into another folder.

How can this be done using a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over files in the first directory. For each file in it check if it's present in the other directory. If it's present then move both files to the other directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
for F in f1/*
do 
    test -f $F && test -f f2/${F#*/} && echo cp $F f3/
done
```

It's a good idea to get to know parameter expansion in situations like this.  Above, the construct `${F#*/}` is equivalent to `$(basename $F)` but much faster because it doesn't execute **basename**(1) for each iteration.

If you have lots of files, and you don't really need to test if the files are *regular* files, you might speed things up by avoiding the loop, by generating a script.  Something like:

```
mkfifo .f1 .f2
(cd f1 && ls > ../.f1)& (cd f2 && ls > ../.f2)& 
comm -12 .f1 .f2 | sed 's:^.*$:cp f1/& f3/:' | sh
rm .f1 .f2
```

I'm assuming for the sake of illustration that the filenames don't include spaces or other weird characters.  If they do, of course the parameters will need quoting.